# List of Languages, where to look for

Tags: organization

It is not programming related but surely is development related.

I need a list of Human Spoken Languages (Normally we see on every other site to choose from),
required in one of our projects. would be great, if holds Language Codes information  as well,  and in **.txt format or any other, extractable one**.

- Is there a resource over the web
  where we can find simmilar thigs like
  the one above or like List of
  Countries or List of bla bla blah,
  published according to some approved
  **body / org**

Thanks

Comment: Maybe something like the list of ISO language codes? You can find it on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) and at the bottom of that page are links to codes defined in other standards as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ISO 639 is a good place to start.

Here are a couple of pages maintained by the US Library of Congress:

http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

http://www.loc.gov:8081/standards/iso639-5/id.php

Browse the site, they also have computer parsable plain text versions.

**update**: forgot about sil.org. There's a list of ISO 639-3 available from their site:

http://www.sil.org/iso639-3

Answer (score 3):

[Ethnologue](http://www.ethnologue.com/web.asp) is a well known resource.